# PHP variables inside SQL results?

Tags: php, sql

So, if I say

```
$bike = 'Schwinn';
```

Can I have a select statement that returns `Your bike is a $bike.` and have `echo $statement` be `Your bike is a Schwinn.` without additional parsing?

Comment: No. You can do really terrible thing to the security of your code and then maybe have that work, but I'm going to leave this at 'No'.

Comment: You want to google for **prepared statements**.

Comment: It will be much easier if you build your string in your php app instead of your query. All you need to do is get `Schwinn` from your database and use it in your string

Answer (score 0):

By using the [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function in MySQL you can:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Your bike is a ', bike, '.') as 'Bike' FROM bicycles where bike = 'Schwinn'
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a65277/8)